# remove all the nodes which have greater value on right(Linked list)

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Given a singly linked list, remove all the nodes which have a greater value on right side.  This is not a home work and it was asked me in an interview.

e.g.

input:

> 2--->4--->2--->1--->3--->0

then the output should be

> 4--->3--->0.

input:

> 30--->40--->50--->60

then the output should be

> 60

**My approach was below:**

```
1. reverse the link list
2. maintain the max value if the current node is less than max than remove else move next
3. reverse again
```

But the interviewer asked me to optimize this. I think he was expecting the same as mentioned by @Trying.

Comment: Reversing list seems like a problem to me, and you are doing it twice! Just modify step 2 so reversing is not used before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time complexity O(N). please let me know if you have any doubts. Thanks.

```
Node delete(Node n){
        if(n==null){
            return null;
        }
        Node t = delete(n.next);
        if(t==null){
            return n; // i.e. right most node so just return this
        }
        else{
            Comparable c = (Comparable)n.k;
            if(c.compareTo((Comparable)t.k)<0){ //no need of this node so return t.
                return t;
            }
            else{
                n.next=t; //valid node so change the next pointer of current node
                return n;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem, and borrow from the solution.

```
decreasingList(List list) {
    if list empty then return empty

    List restSolution = decreasingList(list.next)
    ... list.first ... // What now
```

Ask yourself, having the `restSolution` and `list.first` what you should return.

*This makes computer science sooo much funnier than math: laziness, doing just a bit, and delegating work.*

---

***Sorry thought this was homework***

```
static class List {
    int value;
    List next;

    List(int value, List next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    static List makeList(int... values) {
        List list = null;
        List tail = null;
        for (int value: values) {
            List node = new List(value, null);
            if (tail == null) {
                list = node;
            } else {
                tail.next = node;
            }
            tail = node;
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (next == null) {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
        return String.valueOf(value) + "-->" + next.toString();
    }
}

static List decreasingList(List list) {
    if (list == null) {
        return null;
    }
    List rest = decreasingList(list.next);
    if (rest != null && list.value < rest.value) {
        return rest;
    }
    list.next = rest;
    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List list = List.makeList(2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 0);
    System.out.println("List: " + list);
    list = decreasingList(list);
    System.out.println("Decreasing: " + list);
}
```

The recursion might be resolved, just as you did: reversal by walking the nexts and changing the next to the prior node. And then at the tail going back.

```
static List decreasingList(List list) {
    List prior = null;
    while (list != null) {
        List next = list.next;
        list.next = prior;
        prior = list;
        list = next;
    }
    list = prior; // The reversed list.

    prior = null;
    while (list != null) {
        List next = list.next;
        list.next = prior;
        if (prior == null || list.value > prior.value) {
            prior = list;
        }
        list = next;
    }
    list = prior;
    return list;
}
```